# Display only unique entries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a mysql based chat application.

My database schema has the following tables,

```
       Users               Messages
   =================   =================
        id                 id
        screen_name        message
                           from
                           to
                           timestamp
```

The from and to fields on the messages table contain the id's of the users that sent and received each message.

I am trying to display all messages between a user ($id) and one of their friends ($friend). My query is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT messages.* , users.screen_name FROM users CROSS JOIN messages ";
$query .= "ON ( messages.to = $id AND messages.from = $friend ) ";
$query .= "OR ( messages.to = $friend AND messages.from = $id )";
```

The problem is that every message is twice in the result table.

I tried using DISTINCT but it either doesn't work in this scenario or I used it wrong.

What should my query be in order to have each message between the two users only once?

Comment: Seems to be doing the trick. Could you please explain it briefly in an answer so I can award rep?

Comment: You are selecting `messages.*`. Using `SELECT DISTINCT`, if any one of those fields are different (regardless of whether or not the message is the same), then you will get both rows. I would suggest that you don't use `SELECT *`, but instead explicitly select each individual field that you actually want. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  messages.*,
  users_from.screen_name AS from_screen_name,
  users_to.screen_name AS to_screen_name
FROM
  messages
    JOIN users AS users_from ON messages.from = users_from.id
    JOIN users AS users_to ON messages.to = users_to.id
WHERE
  (messages.to = $id AND messages.from = $friend)
  OR ( messages.to = $friend AND messages.from = $id)
```

What this does is joing the "users" table twice, once on the "to" column and the second time on the "from" column.

Answer (score 1):

@Travesty3 has already suggested that the `DISTINCT` keyword will only exclude duplicate rows where *all* fields are equal to another row. Therefore, the `DISTINCT` keyword is not the way to go here.

What you can do, however, is to simply `GROUP BY messages.id` in order to get only one row per message ID (there is no guarantee, however, as to which of the two rows will be excluded).

Comment: This seem to work fine, but so does the double join proposed by Jan. Is there a difference in performance between the two?

Comment: @AnPel Given that the fields used for the `JOIN` s and `GROUP BY` are indexed, I suspect both to perform more than satisfactory. What you could do is to benchmark using example queries on realistic data sets.